# Reduce total sum of vector elements in R

Tags: r

in R, I have a vector of integers. From this vector, I would like to reduce the value of each integer element randomly, in order to obtain a sum of the vector that is a percentage of the initial sum.

In this example, I would like to reduce the vector "x" to a vector "y", where each element has been randomly reduced to obtain a sum of the elements equal to 50% of the initial sum.

The resulting vector should have values that are non-negative and below the original value.

```
set.seed(1)
perc<-50            
x<-sample(1:5,10,replace=TRUE)
xsum<-sum(x) # sum is 33
toremove<-floor(xsum*perc*0.01)
x # 2 2 3 5 2 5 5 4 4 1

y<-magicfunction(x,perc)
y # 0 2 1 4 0 3 2 1 2 1
sum(y) # sum is 16 (rounded half of 33)
```

Can you think of a way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I'm confused, but I don't quite follow why based on your description you can't just do `0.5 * x`? Is there some other criteria that you haven't mentioned?

Comment: Can we assume that the vector is long? With at least, say, 200 elements?

Comment: @JuliusVainora yes, the vector can be arbitrarily long

Comment: @joran sorry, I clarified it: the vector reduction should not be proportional to each element, but random

Comment: @MilanValášek good question: no, the minimum value should be non-negative and below the original value.

Comment: Am I right to assume you'd like to avoid computationally inefficient solutions, e.g., sample random integers until their sum is sum(x)/2 and then repeatedly randomly subtract them from x until you get a vector with no negative values?

Comment: You said half and your sum is 16 `sum(y) sum is 16 (half of 33)`? confused!

Comment: @MAPK yep sorry, 16 it's half of 33 rounded (actually, rounded to the previous integer with the floor function)

Comment: @MilanValášek good thinking, but yes I would like to avoid the brute force approach of reducing the elements until the sum matches what I need. But thumbs up for providing a possible solution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `x` is long enough, we may rely on some appropriate law of large numbers (also assuming that `x` is regular enough in certain other ways). For that purpose we will generate values of another random variable Z taking values in [0,1] and with mean `perc`.

```
set.seed(1)
perc <- 50 / 100
x <- sample(1:10000, 1000)
sum(x)
# [1] 5014161
x <- round(x * rbeta(length(x), perc / 3 / (1 - perc), 1 / 3))
sum(x)
# [1] 2550901
sum(x) * 2
# [1] 5101802
sum(x) * 2 / 5014161 
# [1] 1.017479 # One percent deviation
```

Here for Z I chose a certain beta distribution giving mean `perc`, but you could pick some other too. The lower the variance, the more precise the result. For instance, the following is much better as the previously chosen beta distribution is, in fact, bimodal:

```
set.seed(1)
perc <- 50 / 100
x <- sample(1:1000, 100)
sum(x)
# [1] 49921
x <- round(x * rbeta(length(x), 100 * perc / (1 - perc), 100))
sum(x)
# [1] 24851
sum(x) * 2
# [1] 49702
sum(x) * 2 / 49921
# [1] 0.9956131 # Less than 0.5% deviation!
```

Comment: I am totally and thoroughly impressed by this solution!

Comment: @FedericoGiorgi, the choice of this Z is really important, as I'm demonstrating in the answer. If you care about the error, you may pick some distribution that is very concentrated around `perc`, perhaps taking values only in some interval [perc - epsilon, perc + epsilon]. That said, depending on the details of your problem, the solution can be improved.

Comment: As you lower the variance on the beta distribution, you are essentially doing `x <- round(perc * x)`.

Comment: Yes, in the limit. The question is how much of this randomness (variance) is needed for the actual problem. However, you won't be able to achieve super low variance with beta while maintaining the desired mean. So, some other distribution would be needed then.

Comment: @JuliusVainora in fact, more randomness would be better mmm

Comment: @FedericoGiorgi, among other properties, symmetry, lower variance, and narrower interval of possible values help precision, while higher variance and wider interval would increase "randomness". So, you may experiment with those parameters. Currently your problem description doesn't provide any information of what any of those should be, and that's not really a programming question anymore anyway.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution is this function, which downsamples the original vector by a random fraction proportional to the vector element size. Then it checks that elements don't fall below zero, and iteratively approaches an optimal solution.

```
removereads<-function(x,perc=NULL){
xsum<-sum(x)
toremove<-floor(xsum*perc)
toremove2<-toremove
irem<-1
while(toremove2>(toremove*0.01)){
    message("Downsampling iteration ",irem)
    tmp<-sample(1:length(x),toremove2,prob=x,replace=TRUE)
    tmp2<-table(tmp)
    y<-x
    common<-as.numeric(names(tmp2))
    y[common]<-x[common]-tmp2
    y[y<0]<-0
    toremove2<-toremove-(xsum-sum(y))
    irem<-irem+1
}
return(y)
}
set.seed(1)
x<-sample(1:1000,10000,replace=TRUE)
perc<-0.9
y<-removereads(x,perc)
plot(x,y,xlab="Before reduction",ylab="After reduction")
abline(0,1)
```

And the graphical results:
[image: Downsampling R vector]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution which uses draws from the Dirichlet distribution:

```
set.seed(1)
x = sample(10000, 1000, replace = TRUE)

magic = function(x, perc, alpha = 1){
    # sample from the Dirichlet distribution
    # sum(p) == 1
    # lower values should reduce by less than larger values
    # larger alpha means the result will have more "randomness"
    p = rgamma(length(x), x / alpha, 1)
    p = p / sum(p)

    # scale p up an amount so we can subtract it from x
    # and get close to the desired sum
    reduce = round(p * (sum(x) - sum(round(x * perc))))
    y = x - reduce

    # No negatives
    y = c(ifelse(y < 0, 0, y))

    return (y)
    }

alpha = 500
perc = 0.7
target = sum(round(perc * x))
y = magic(x, perc, alpha)

# Hopefully close to 1
sum(y) / target
> 1.000048

# Measure of the "randomness"
sd(y / x)
> 0.1376637
```

Basically, it tries to figure out how much to reduce each element by while still getting close to the sum you want. You can control how "random" you want the new vector by increasing `alpha`.